# String was not recognized as valid datetime after add BETWEEN statement in choosing date asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

i have this problem occur after i add statement BETWEEN to choose between two dates and display the data. Before this it works when i choose only one date. this problem occur when i want to choose another value other than date. it appear string not recognized as valid datetime. but if i choose that value with date or date only, it does not appear any error. why this happen ? it works perfectly when only i have one date to choose but error when i add between statement in the date. this is my code so far.

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue)) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxSearchRec.Text)) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxSearchRec2.Text)) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListProcess.SelectedValue)))
       {

           try
           {
               con.Open();

               //select data from CutPanelCard
               query = "select a.req_id, a.prod_line, a.jo_no, a.buyer, a.request_date,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.need_by_date ,101) as need_by_date, a.qty, a.username, b.process_id from CutPanelCard a LEFT JOIN CutPanelConfirmation b on b.req_id = a.req_id ";

               //check if dropdownJO not empty so query the data
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue))
               {
                   query += "where jo_no=@jo_no and status='F' ";
                   cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jo_no", DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue);
                   checking = true;

               }

               //check if dropdownLine not empty so query the data
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue))
               {
                   if (checking == true)
                   {
                       query += "and prod_line=@prod_line and status='F' ";
                       cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_line", DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jo_no", DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxSearchRec.Text));
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxSearchRec2.Text));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       query += "where prod_line=@prod_line and status='F' ";
                       cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_line", DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jo_no", DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue);
                       checking = true;
                   }
               }

              //check if dropdownProcess not empty so query the data
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListProcess.SelectedValue))
               {
                       if (checking == true)
                       {
                           query += "and a.req_id not in (select req_id from cutpanelconfirmation where process_id = @process_id) and status='F' ";
                           cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@processs_id", DropDownListProcess.SelectedValue);
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jo_no", DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue);
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_line", DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           query += "where a.req_id not in (select req_id from cutpanelconfirmation where process_id = @process_id) and status='F' ";
                           cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_id", DropDownListProcess.SelectedValue);
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jo_no", DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue);
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_line", DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue);
                           checking = true;
                       }
               }

               //check if textboxRec not empty so query the data
               if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxSearchRec.Text)) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxSearchRec2.Text)))
               {
                   if (checking == true)
                   {
                       query += "and need_by_date BETWEEN @from and @to and status='F' ";
                       cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxSearchRec.Text));
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxSearchRec2.Text));
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jo_no", DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_line", DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_id", DropDownListProcess.SelectedValue);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       query += "where need_by_date BETWEEN @from and @to and status='F' ";
                       cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@need_by_date", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxSearchRec.Text));
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxSearchRec2.Text));
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jo_no", DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_line", DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_id", DropDownListProcess.SelectedValue);
                       checking = true;
                   }
               }


               //show the query based on ascending req_id and last_update
               query += "order by a.req_id, b.last_update DESC ";
               cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxSearchRec.Text));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxSearchRec2.Text));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jo_no", DropDownListSearchJO.SelectedValue);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_line", DropDownListSearchLine.SelectedValue);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_id", DropDownListProcess.SelectedValue);

               SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

               //remove duplicated req_id before bind into gridview
               DataTable dtRemoveDuplicate = new DataTable();
               da.Fill(dtRemoveDuplicate);
               dtRemoveDuplicate = DeleteDuplicateFromDataTable(dtRemoveDuplicate, "req_id");
               GridView1.DataSource = dtRemoveDuplicate;
               GridView1.DataBind();

               con.Close();
           }
```

Comment: debug and see the actual values.

Comment: it appear error string not recognized as valid datetime when choosing another options other than date when run

Comment: yes that is the result, but you should debug and see why and where the error is, and nobody can help you debug.

Comment: I would create 2 DateTime values for _To_ & _From_ and then populate with those textboxes... should help with debugging

Comment: @MadMychewhere what you means by two datetime values ? create in database ?

Answer (score -2):

try this.

```
query += "and a.need_by_date BETWEEN @from and @to and status='F' ";
query += "where a.need_by_date BETWEEN @from and @to and status='F' ";
```

Comment: use datePicker control instead of textbox

Comment: for example ? im sorry because i till new with this c# and visual studio

Comment: try this."Select data from tablename  where date>=startdate and date<=enddate"

Comment: still not working. this work when i have only one textbox date before. but when i add between for query for date it not working :( i just add another one textbox and between statement :(

Comment: if you are using textbox to get date, maybe format is wrong.
string dateS = @"20/07/2017";
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
The following code throws FormatException: 
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
In this code dateS represents Date in Day/Month/Year format.
By default .NET uses en-US culture. So when toDateTime method
used it throws error because 20 is out of Month range.
string dateString = @"20/05/2012";
Try this.
Convert.ToDateTime(dateString,
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);